# Address already in use after attempting socket connection

Tags: java, linux, sockets

Hi I'm new to java socket and I've been trying to create a server socket. I know this question may have been asked but i would like for someone to look at my code please. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong because I'm getting an error saying "Address already in use" Help please? I have also realised that with some research that I may have run two servers simultaneously. Can anyone please explain please?Here's the server class and the client class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MessageServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    //int port = 25000;

    //int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 

    ServerSocket serverr = new ServerSocket(3456);

    while(true){

        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        //ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(53705);
        //System.out.println("listening on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        Socket client = serverr.accept();

        System.out.println("Client from " + client.getInetAddress() + " connected.");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client said: '"+inputLine+"'");
        Writer count = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        byte c [] = count.toString().getBytes();
        count.flush();
        //server.close();

    } 

}
}





import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MessageSendClient {

public static void man(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Socket client = new Socket ("localhost", 3456);
    System.out.println("Connected to " + client.getInetAddress());
    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();

    byte c[] = new byte[100];
    int num = in.read(c);
    String count = new String(c);

    System.out.println("Server said: " + count);
    client.close();
    }
}
```

Exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use at
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) at     
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376) at 
    java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376) at 
    java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237) at
    java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128) at 
    MessageServer.main(MessageServer.java:18)
```

Comment: the code seems to be fine, have you got another instance of your program running? Try another port.

Comment: @user432
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
 at MessageServer.main(MessageServer.java:18)
.. I have changed the IP adress to localhost and the port number to an available one and i still get that error message

Comment: I tested it and the code is working fine. The error indicates that the port is already used.

Comment: I don't understand how it works for everyone else but not me, really frustrating. I have literally tried like 100 different ports and nothing. Thanks for your help @user432. do u have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with some previous socket (of a previous run of the program) staying alive some time to complete the double ACK on close mechanism. You can bypass that by indicating a specific option to the socket:

```
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
```

(where `socket` is your server socket).

Comment: Thanks for the useful advice but unfortunately I'm still getting the "address already in use" still :/

Comment: Check again. You may be putting that to the client socket instead of the server one. There is no more reasons you're getting this error.

Comment: Maybe its these university computers are a bit dodgy. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user3576868 No computer is dodgy in this respect.

Comment: A port will stay alive for some time *after* the close mechanism.

Comment: My problem is that once i find an available port, I executed using that port on the server. Then when I try to executed the client who also has the same port number then says the Address already in use. Its like it doesnt allow me to use the same port for the server and the client. Do you understand what I'm trying to say? It's basically saying no to me when I run server and client with same port number. @EJP

Comment: @user3576868 The code you posted is server code, not client code. If you're trying to have two processes listening at the same port, (a) they are both servers, and (b) you can't.

Comment: @EJP scroll to bottom of the code. I have the client class at the bottom. Could u tell me if you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Why do you ask? The exceptions you've posted all come from the server. When you say the client throws this exception, you are mistaken. It doesn't.

Comment: Hi, the method setReuseAddress() seems to be unavailable now.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. A previous instance of your code is still running: terminate it.
2. Something else is listening at the port: bad luck.
3. A connection port is still in the TIME_WAIT state after the previous instance of your program had exited. Either wait two minutes, or create your ServerSocket as follows:

   ```
   ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(); // create an unbound socket
   ss.setReuseAddress(true);
   ss.bind(...); // argument(s) left as an exercise for the reader
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This error message means some application has already created a socket on the port you specified (`3456`).

To resolve the problem you need either change this port to some other, or find out which program occupies it and terminate this program. In Linux, you can do this with `netstat` command:

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep :3456
```

For more details on `netstat` command, see [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/).

When you have identified the process using technique I wrote above, you may want to kill it. Let's assume the `PID` of the process is `1234`. Then we gonna need this command:

```
# kill -9 1234
```

You may need `root` privileges to do that.

If none of this helps, it is also possible that some external software is blocking your connections. It can be `selinux`, it can be network firewall settings - consider checking that too.

Comment: That would be amazing if only I had the root privileges haha

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in that when you tested your code twice you didnt fully kill the previous process.

Comment: It could also be due to a port still in the TIME_WAIT state.